# How to centre media on Zebra QLN220 printers

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, calibration

The media Im printing on is 40mm and the Zebra QLN220 is set to 48mm which means some of the text is cut off how do i adjust this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing using ZPL commands the code to add would be:

^xa^PW320^xz

The printhead is 8 dots per millimeter. The PW sets the print width in dots. 8*40 = 320

If you are using a driver, CPCL, or line mode you need to look up how to change the print width for those methods.